# passwords and permissions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, assign

This might come across as a simple question, but I have very limited experience with relational databases. How do I fine tune permissions in MySQL. For example, if I have the following code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

//...other columns

PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pictures
(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userID INT NOT NULL,

//...other columns

PRIMARY KEY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES user(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB";
```

and I create two new users, `user1` and `user2`, I can give them permission to the tables as such

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES ON db_name.* to ".user1."@\"%\" identified by ".pass1
GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES ON db_name.* to ".user2."@\"%\" identified by ".pass2
```

but is there anywhere to restrict privileges inside a table to only a specific subset? Should I carry this out in my PHP code instead? I'm used to object oriented programming, so I am not accustomed to massive tables which hold all the information.

Comment: You want to give access to a particular table or column?

Comment: sorry, I meant specific rows. Obviously in that example, you wouldn't want `user1` having access to rows in the `pictures` table that belong to `user2`. Does MySQL provide operations to deal with this, or do I have to carry this out in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, you can't grant access to some rows of a table and not others, which sounds like what you are asking to do.

Comment: Yes I see that now. My mistake was in thinking that MySQL database users had to have a 1-1 correspondence with real life users.

Comment: @puk think of it more as a 'role' than a user.  You can give 'admin' access to certain tables, 'auditor' read access to everything and so on.  It is useful, but it doesn't match what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing your permissioning for end-users of your application in PHP. Using database users to control access is an antiquated method (in my opinion) and can be difficult to do/support in MySQL/PHP as its not commonly done.

Comment: So, for example, if I have a table with pictures (picture file names) indexed by the foreign ID `userID`, I should use php to manage who has access to what. I just assumed that having users in MySQL would be meant for just such situations.

Comment: You should always ensure that the database is protected from the outside world.  You should ONLY ever give select access from the database until someone has been authenticated or they have entered some type of input to verify themselves which protects the database from bad users.  Also only allowing selects from certain tables and ensuring that the updates/inserts are only done by certain users on only qualified tables that they are SUPPOSED to write to is important.  Protect the database; otherwise you end up getting hacked easily.

Comment: @puk Correct. Database users are for controlling what permissions an application has - not what permissions a specific user of the application has.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, that's what I thought.

Comment: @suroot: I understand that the database should not be completely open, but I imagine that there are only ever a handful of database users (ie readUser, writerUser...) regardless of how many real users there are.

Comment: @puk: I would agree that having a level of readUser and writeUser but you should also strive to add more segmentation between certain tables.  (i.e. the user that is reading from the UserLogin table should not be the same user that can read from the general table).

Answer (score 0):

In the [Grant Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) you'll need to check the docs to see what specific privileges you are looking for; but you'll need to perform multiple grants for the same user for each separate privilege (i.e. one for select, one for update, etc...).